# Error in MuPDF rendering on new versions of Android

Tags: android, eclipse, mupdf

I used the MuPDF library in my old android project (built with eclipse), and  now my app has crashes on smartphones with Android version 7.0.

The problem, is that in my smartphone (MotoG version 5.0), the application renders the PDF normally.

The error:

```
Rendering page(1)=1042x1560 patch=[0,0,1042,1560]
03-01 12:45:48.954 28065-28065/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-01 12:45:48.978 28065-28065/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: br.com.forcommerce.californiacoffee, PID: 28065
                                               java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Não suportado
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ReaderView.getSelectedView(ReaderView.java:661)
                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(AdapterView.java:985)
                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6543)
                                                   at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:6502)
                                                   at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:6487)
                                                   at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:145)
                                                   at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:6439)
                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(AdapterView.java:994)
                                                   at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:6427)
                                                   at android.widget.AdapterView.onRequestSendAccessibilityEventInternal(AdapterView.java:966)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:914)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewGroup.java:887)
                                                   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:6298)
                                                   at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:6277)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7493)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$SendWindowContentChangedAccessibilityEvent.runOrPost(ViewRootImpl.java:7519)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.postSendWindowContentChangedCallback(ViewRootImpl.java:6635)
                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewRootImpl.java:6819)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3139)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3139)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3139)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3139)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:3139)
                                                   at android.view.View.notifySubtreeAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(View.java:9431)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4777)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:4730)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:4661)
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.PageView$2.onPostExecute(PageView.java:292)
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.PageView$2.onPostExecute(PageView.java:1)
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:634)
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.AsyncTask.access$0(AsyncTask.java:630)
                                                   at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                   at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
03-01 12:45:48.986 1542-6704/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity br.com.forcommerce.californiacoffee/com.artifex.mu
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you